# CheckBox Ajax Filter yajra datatable

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I wanna click on checkbox on yajra datatable if click on available i want fetch data according to the controller conditions the problem is the table is not refreshing  ... here is the view

```
                    <div class="col-sm-12">
                            <div class="col-sm-3"><input type="checkbox" name="available" id=available"  >Available</div>
                            <div class="col-sm-3">  <input type="checkbox" name="unavailable" id="unavailable" >Unavailable</div>

                    <div class="card-title">

                            <a href="{{url('/admin/promocode/add')}}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" id="reloadTableButton"> Add New Code </a>
                    </div>

                            </div>


                    <div class="card-text">


                        <table id="items_datatable" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0"
                               width="100%">
                            <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Code</th>
                                <th>Count</th>
                                <th>Status</th>
                                <th>From</th>
                                <th>To</th>
                                 <th>Created At</th>
                                  <th>Updated At</th>

                                <th>Actions</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>


                        </table>


                        <!-- Table End-->
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        </div> <!-- container -->
    </div> <!-- content -->
</div>
```

and here is function in controller,, i want if i select available checkbox it fetch the records which has status or active = 1 and if i click unavailable it fetch records which has status = 0 and if i checked both of them it fetch all

```
public function Promocodeslist()
    {   
        $available=Input::get('available');
        $unavailable=Input::get('unavailable');
if($available ==1  && $unavailable == 0 ){
            $promocodes = DB::table('promocodes')->select('id','code','userscount','active','sfrom','sto','created_at','updated_at')->where('active',1)->get();
}elseif($unavailable == 1  && $available == 0){
            $promocodes = DB::table('promocodes')->select('id','code','userscount','active','sfrom','sto','created_at','updated_at')->where('active',0)->get();
}else{
       $promocodes = DB::table('promocodes')->select('id','code','userscount','active','sfrom','sto','created_at','updated_at')->get();
}        return Datatables::of($promocodes)->make(true);   
}
```

here is ajax call

```
<script>


 <?php $editurl = url('/admin/promocode/');?>
 var available = 0;
 var unavailable=0;
 var ckbox = $('#available');
 var ckbox1=$('#unavailable');


 var table = $('#items_datatable').DataTable({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        destroy:true,
        ajax: '{!! route("promocodes_list",["available"=> 'available',"unavailable" => 'unavailable']) !!}',
        columns: [

            {data: 'code', name: 'code'},
            {data: 'userscount', name: 'userscount'},
            {data: 'active', name: 'active'},
            {data: 'sfrom', name: 'sfrom'},
            {data: 'sto', name: 'sto'},
            {data: 'created_at', name: 'created_at'},
            {data: 'updated_at', name: 'updated_at'},
            {
                data: 'id', render: function (data) 
                {
                    return "<a href='{{$editurl}}" + '/' + data + '/edit' + "' class='btn btn-w" + "arning'><i class='fa fa-pencil' data-toggle='tooltip' data-placement='top' title='Edit Deliver-Order' ></i></a> "; 
                    }
            }]

        });
  $('input').on('click',function () {
        if (ckbox.is(':checked')) {
             available = 1;
        } else {
            available=0;
        }
     table.ajax.reload();

    });


  $('input').on('click',function () {
        if (ckbox1.is(':checked')) {
             unavailable = 1;
        } else {
            unavailable=0;
        }
     table.ajax.reload();

    });
```